# downloading Android binary(apk) in php , parsing error package when installing apk file

Tags: php, parsing, download, installation, apk

I am trying to download an Android APK file that is output by a php page.
Downloading is success, But parsing package problem occur when try to install the apk file.
Actually, access the filepath(/var/www/xxx/HelloWorldTest.apk) directly, this method installed completely.(no problem.)
But I want to use the method that via the php source.

I have Android app on my server and also have php code like:

```
<?php
$path = "/var/www/xxx/";
$filename="HelloWorldTest.apk";
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path . $filename));
readfile($path . $filename);
?>
```

Have HelloWorldTest(Android app) Manifest like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.helloworldtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.helloworldtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My setup:
CentOS release 6.3 (Final),2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64, PHP 5.3.17
Android table Version:3.2.1 kernel version:2.6.36.3

There is difference of binary dump in using direct access method and using php method result.

direct access(success)

```
50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 08  08 00 F5 91 76 42 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 1C 00 04 00 72 65 
73 2F 6C 61 79 6F 75 74  2F 61 63 74 69 76 69 74 
79 5F 6D 61 69 6E 2E 78  6D 6C FE CA 00 00 6D 91
...
```

via php(install failed)

```
0A 0A 50 4B 03 04 14 00  08 08 08 00 F5 91 76 42 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 1C 00 04 00 
72 65 73 2F 6C 61 79 6F  75 74 2F 61 63 74 69 76 
69 74 79 5F 6D 61 69 6E  2E 78 6D 6C FE CA 00 00
.....
```

The problem seems to initial part [0A 0A] was added in binary code.

Answer (score 3):

0A is the hex code for line feed.  So you appear to have two line feeds added before the actual content of the file.  From reading the docs on [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php), it recommends surrounding the readfile call with the following:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($path . $filename);
exit;
```

Try that and see if you still have the two 0A characters.